# Sensenet: It is possible to filter directly on a column on a List view?

Tags: .net, sensenet

It is possible to filter by column on a "list view"? (without editing views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately is not possible without some coding or as you mentioned without editing views.